# Minimum number of edges to be added so that one can reach all vertices from root?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

[image]

Here 1 is the root by adding edge from 1 to 3 and 2 to 4 one can reach all vertices from 1.
What's the algorithm for achieving this?

Comment: Hint: each additional edge reduces the number of connected components by at most one.

Answer (score 1):

As with most problems on reachability in directed graphs, this should be solved in two steps:

1. Solve the problem in an [acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).
2. Apply the solution in step 1 to the [condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_(graph_theory)) of the graph: the directed acyclic graph obtained by replacing each strongly connected component by a single vertex.

---

Suppose first that our directed graph has no cycles. (For this purpose, we ignore edges into the desired root vertex; if they exist, we pretend they don't, because they will never help us.)

Every vertex in the directed graph is reachable from *some* vertex of indegree $0$: just follow edges *backward* arbitrarily until you reach such a vertex. (Because the graph is acyclic, we will never repeat vertices in this process, so it must end eventually - and it can only end when we reach a vertex of indegree $0$.) Therefore it's enough to add edges from the desired root to every other vertex of indegree $0$.

On the other hand, that's also an optimal solution: we need to add *some* edge to every such vertex, otherwise they will not be reachable from anywhere else.

So in this case, the minimum number of edges is just the minimum number of indegree-$0$ vertices, ignoring the vertex that will be our root.

(This is the situation in the example in the question: vertices $3$ and $4$ have indegree $0$, and if we add edges $1 \to 3$ and $1 \to 4$, then all vertices are reachable from vertex $1$.)

---

In a graph with cycles, this is not necessarily true. Consider a graph with vertices $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and edges $\{2 \to 3, 3 \to 4, 4 \to 2\}$. If we want every vertex to be reachable from $1$, we need to add an edge, even though no other vertices have indegree $0$.

The solution is to take the condensation: replace every strongly connected component by a single vertex. We do this because if we can reach *one* vertex in a strongly connected component, we can reach them all (by definition, any vertex in a strongly connected component can reach any other).

The condensation is a directed acyclic graph, so the solution from our previous section applies to it.

A way to summarize the combination of solutions is: the minimum number of edges we need is the number of strongly connected components, other than the strongly connected component containing our desired root, which *are not reachable from outside the strongly connected component*. (In the condensation, these are exactly the strongly connected components which will have indegree $0$.)

A solution that achieves this just adds one arbitrary edge from the desired root to each of the strongly connected components we counted.